# How to convert timestamp without timezone and integer representing timezone to a new timestamp without timezone in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timestamp, timezone

Let's say I have a table with two fields: snapshot_date (timestamp without timezone) and timezone (integer),

| snapshot_date | timezone |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-12 08:00:00 | -3 |
| 2021-01-12 00:00:00 | -5 |

I need to extract the local hour from this table, I tried with `(EXTRACT (hour from timestamp))::integer + timezone`, this would work for the first row, giving an hour result of `5` but with the second row you get `-5`, which should actually be `19` since the corresponding date adjusted with timezone is `2021-01-11 19:00:00`. So what I want to do is calculate a new snapshot_date adjusted with the timezone, so I can correctly extract the hour after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get the expected result with:

```
extract(hour from snapshot_date + interval '1 hour' * timezone)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to first add the number of hours to the timestamp, then extract the hour:

```
extract(hour from snapshot_date + make_interval(hours => timezone))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
show timezone; US/Pacific 
select ('2021-01-12 08:00:00'::timestamp::text || (-3)::text)::timestamptz; 
2021-01-12 03:00:00-08

select extract(hour from('2021-01-12 08:00:00'::timestamp::text || (-3)::text)::timestamptz);
3
```